# Finding Difference from Previous Day Volume to Next Day Volume

Tags: tableau-api

I have been struggling to find the new incoming volume per day.
I have categories as : - total ticket, Resolved, closed and Daily left.
So the calc is everyday resolved and closed are moved from the queue and
**'daily left = Total Ticket- (Pending + Closed)'**
Now there is some carry forward everyday hence the total ticket for the next day includes some volume i.e. Daily left of previous day.
 I am not able to figure out how to show that number, I have tried using previous value but it is not helping. Please suggest. Attaching a print screen of the data.[image: Please refer to 03-01-17]
For 3rd the # of records are 33 however there is 1 carry forward from previous
day hence the Fresh Vol should be 32. I have used the formula to calc but it is
not giving correct result

```
sum([Number of Records]) - (PREVIOUS_VALUE([Daily Left Volume]))
```

This is taking the left over of current day and not previous day.

I am also using look Up function but that also does not show the current output.
[image: LookUp Function]
The output from tableau after using the lookup function is below attached as well
[image]

Comment: Read the docs on previous_value(). It is useful but doesn't act the way you think it does. Try lookup() instead with an offset of -1

Comment: I had tried lookup() -1 also but that also does not help.

Comment: If you set the table calc partition and addressing correctly, then lookup([some aggregate calculation], -1) will give the value of [some aggregate calculation] for the previous data row -- where previous is defined according to the addressing aka compute using for the calc.

Comment: If you can't get lookup() to do what you need, post details

Comment: `sum([Number Of Records])- LOOKUP(([Daily Left Volume])-1` is the formula i have used however this is not returning correct result. I have attached the output screen shot for reference above

Comment: Try putting the -1 as the second parameter to lookup(), and then learning how to set "compute using" to define what you want an offset of -1 to mean. You could also read the documentation on partitioning and addressing for table calcs and the definition of lookup() in the reference section - both in the online help. That should help you understand.

Comment: Sure Alex let me give it a try and see how it works

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this community and dont have enought reputation to comment :P. So writing few possible solutions here:
1) Make sure the data is sorted by date and is unique on date level. If it is not then Previous or lookup might not work
2) Another solution will be take running_sum of every field and then apply the operations. This should give right answer
3) If this does not will it possible to change the way you import the data? 
    a) Simply create another filed as Date_past = Date-1 in your raw data. 
    b) Duplicate your data.
    c) join the two data sets on Date = Date_past
    d) Now you have all the data of today's date and last day in one field and you can perform operations as you need